# Circular dependency between the following tasks in gradle

Tags: android

I'm running my project in AndroidStudio 3.2, but there is an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug
\--- :app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug
     \--- :app:transformClassesAndDexWithShrinkResForDebug
          \--- :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
               +--- :app:preColdswapDebug
               |    \--- :app:incrementalDebugTasks
               |         +--- :app:transformClassesAndClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug
               |         |    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
               |         |         \--- :app:checkManifestChangesDebug (*)
               |         \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)
               \--- :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
                    +--- :app:preColdswapDebug (*)
                    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

I can still generate APKs manually, but the "Run" button doesn't work.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable instant run from settings

Settings > search for instant run > uncheck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on display"

Comment: Is this option the only one? Because disabling the instant run... Come on...

I had the same issue when adding proguard and shrinkResources

Comment: @HocineB it is the easiest solution
I re-enabled it just now and it didn't happen to me again. probably some dependency update fixed it, or updating to android studio 3.2.1 did it.

Comment: This solved my issue. I disabled instant run in Android Studio->Preference->Instant run

Comment: This was not the problem

Answer (score 8):

As noted by @hocine-b in the comments, this may happen if you enable `shrinkResources` in ProGuard.

It only occurs when Instant Run is enabled, i.e. in debug builds when you press the "Run" button.

You can fix it by only shrinking resources in release builds, for example, in your module's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false  // Avoid conflicts with Instant Run 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No shrink resources, no instant run, still happens