# Android Studio Instant Run Circular Dependency (After update)

Tags: android, android-studio, circular-dependency, instant-run

Just updated Android Studio to  3.2.1 and as always there are problems building existing projects.

This time its a Circular dependency error. After a bit of research found that disabling "Instant Run" resolves this error, but its a useful feature.

Anyone know how to resolve this and keep Instant Run enabled?

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:**checkManifestChangesDebug**
\--- :instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug
     \--- :transformClassesAndDexWithShrinkResForDebug
          \--- :transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
               +--- :preColdswapDebug
               |    \--- :incrementalDebugTasks
               |         +--- :transformClassesAndClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug
               |         |    \--- :transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
               |         |         \--- :**checkManifestChangesDebug** (*)
               |         \--- :transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)
               \--- :transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
                    +--- :preColdswapDebug (*)
                    \--- :transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)
```

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582242/6017001